# Error DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

i don't understand where is the error ...

```
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Animation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using Microsoft.Phone.Controls;


namespace xmldow
{
    public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
    {
        // Constructor
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void clickBott(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            WebClient client = new WebClient();
            client.DownloadStringCompleted += new DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler(client_DownloadStringCompleted);
            client.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri("http://example.net/ddd/my.xml"));

        }

        void client_DownloadStringCompleted(Object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler e)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();


        }
    }
}
```

This is the error:

> Error  1   No overload for 'client_DownloadStringCompleted' matches delegate 'System.Net.DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler'

Thank

Comment: `C` tag removed; `C#` tag added instead

Answer (score 6):

The `client_DownloadStringCompleted` method should look like this instead:

```
private void client_DownloadStringCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```